# Multiple copies of Views filter form (exposed filters)

Tags: 6, blocks, views

I know in views you have the option to expose the filters form as a block, but doing so removes the exposed form from the view page.  Is there any way to expose the filters form as a block and *keep* the exposed form in the view as well?

For example, is there a way to see
[image: Views exposed form]
at the top of my view, but on every other page have an exposed form block like
[image]
in the side bar?

This would be helpful as when a user is on  a view page, he/she will be primarily concentrating on the main content and would look for a search there (instead of in a block on the side of the page).  However, users should be able to search the view from any page on the site (enter block).

Currently I have a custom module creating a block to act as the exposed form block while in Views I have *Expose form in block* set to "No".  Is there an easier way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hack works very well but there's no need for a hack if you have seperate displays from your view. My search results were displayed as a "Page" display and you also have the "Default" display.

On the page you would click "Exposed form in a block" then click "Override" on the right hand side. Set this to "No" (so the form now displays on the search page). In the "Default" display, have "Exposed form in a block" set to "Yes" - so by default it produces a block, but you also get the form to appear on the search page as well.

Thanks guys,
Garry.

Comment: clever :) this seems to be a better approach. hacks are last resorts.

Comment: I don't think this works with Views 3. You can't override the the 'exposed in a block' setting per display, neither can you access the default display directly.

Comment: That's correct. This doesn't work for D7, Views 3. -1

Comment: @Fidelix the question was geared towards D6.  During a tag migration all questions accidentally got the "7" tag.