# Views Exposed filter Multiple times on a Page Or Different id for views exposed filter if added one more time

Tags: 6, blocks, views, dashboard

I added a `views exposed filter` to block and I want to show the block multiple times on the `dashboard` page each can have different choices. Can it possible without adding any other `display`?

Or Can it be possible to change the make the id unique for each occurrences of same `exposed filter`?

My Actual Need is :

I am using `Homebox` module for creating a `Dashboard` for user. I created a `view` with `block display` so user can add it in their `Dashboard` multiple times. I added the `Exposed filter` of `taxonomy terms` and I entered the choices of user in my `custom table`. Now user can add same block with different choices. My questions is how to manage different choices with `blocks`,because `exposed filter` have same form id on each occurrences.

Comment: Hi ; I don't quite understand well. Can we say you need to filter several views by one unique exposed filter ?

Comment: No, I need to same view multiple times on a page having exposed filter. I added remember last choice in views expose filter. If I added it multiple times on my dashboard page, and select any choices then it changes in all block of same type. But I don't want to change in all block.

Comment: Similar: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3827/multiple-copies-of-views-filter-form-exposed-filters

Answer (score 0):

While adding a filter there is a dropdown at the top as 'For', by default 'All displays' are selected, by selecting the specific block that particular filter will be displayed on selected block only. Please try and let me know if it worked.

Comment: I didn't found any option?

Comment: And also I am using only one display. So there is no need of that option as you said.

Comment: you are right, if the same block is being duplicated on the homebox. I am unsure about this doing using the frontend configurations. May be some php patches could do this for you based on the specific form ID.

Comment: Yeah but I didn't found any `patches` for it and I am not so expert to create a `patch` for `views`.